# ASP.NET MVC 5 Razor throws 'Nullable object must have a value' even when the object has value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, nullable

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 with Entity Framework 6 and Razor. I've got the following code:

```
[...]
@foreach (var item in Model) {
  <tr>
    <td>
        @item.Superpower.Title
    </td>
    <td>
[...]
```

However, `@item.Superpower.Title` line throws an `InvalidOperationException` telling that `Nullable object must have a value.` I've worked with nullables and I know exactly what this error means. But the problem is that, I neither have a nullable there, nor a `null` value. `item` is not-nullable and has value, `item.Superpower` is not nullable and has a value, and `item.Superpower.Title` is not nullable and has a value. I can simply verify all:

[image]

I can expand and view all the required properties of both `item` and `item.Superpower` in this context. Why would I get this error with no nullables contributing to the context?

Comment: Are you sure the error is happening on the string property `Title`?

Comment: @JustinHelgerson well, the exception is thrown at that line. it could be `item` or `item.Superpower` too, but they are not nullables too.

Comment: Razor has the habit of highlighting a previous line instead of where the error occurs. Check the following lines for nulls.

Comment: @JeowLiHuan yes, it was it. the problem was caused by another line a few lines after the highlighted one. could you please post your solution as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Razor has the habit of highlighting a previous line instead of where the error occurs. Check the following lines for nulls.